# Handler to act as a timer

Tags: android

Hi I'm trying to use a handler to update my GUI every second with random information - the info isn't important just the timer. I have created several handlers and the second handler is suppose to to the job.

Correct me if I'm wrong here: 
Each handler is associate with one thread; i.e. the thread the handler is created in. Therefore if I create a handler in the onCreate() method it will be attached to the GUI thread; the main thread. 
So, in order to get a task/message/method to run at a given time I should use the handler.postDelayed() method. Below is a snippet of my code:

```
// Button to use handler - commence when pressed 
    handler2Btn = (Button)findViewById( R.id.handler2_Btn );
    handler2Btn.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() 
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            new Thread()
            {
                @Override
                public void run() 
                {
                    // Create a new thread which will get the message from handler 1 and send it
                    // when the button has been clicked
                    Message msg2 = handler2.obtainMessage( 1,"New Message for Handler 2" );
                    handler2.sendMessage( msg2 );

                    // Remove any callbacks (messages pending)
                    handler2.removeCallbacks( this );
                    handler2.postDelayed( updateGUI(), 1000 );

                } // End Run

            }.start();// Start the Thread

        }// End on Click
    });
```

And the updateGUI() method which is suppose to act update the GUI and ensure the Textview assigned acts like a timer:

```
private Runnable updateGUI()
{
    return new Runnable()
    {

        // Do this every second
        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
            handlerLabelTxt2.append( ""+j );
            j++;
        }

    };
}
```

But what Im getting is, when I press the button, the GUI updates but doesn't keep updating every second. The intention is to use the button to start the process but have the process continue on its on, acting like a timer.

Should i move the postDelayed() method into the main body of the onCreate() method? I need a bit of help here as Handlers are confusing me!

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried adding handler2.postDelayed( updateGUI(), 1000 ); to the end of your run() method inside the updateGUI() function?

Comment: Tried it and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok - so I got it sorted. I used a combination of a handler and runnable in order to get a certain task to run. I used one of two ways to do it. The first is by implementing runnable:

```
public class timerTask extends Activity implements Runnable
{
private Handler handler;

// TextView for the counter
private TextView counter;

// Button for the stopping the counter
private Button stop;

// Counter
private int i = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView( R.layout.timertask );

    // TextView to be updated
    counter = ( TextView ) findViewById( R.id.counter );

    // Attach the handler here
    handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed( this, 1000 ); 

    // Button to stop the runnable - Work in progress, please ignore
    stop = ( Button ) findViewById( R.id.stop );
    stop.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages( timerTask.class );

        }
    });
}

@Override
public void run() 
{
    counter.setText( " "+i );
    handler.postDelayed( this, 1000 );
    i++;
}

}
```

handler.postDelayed() schedules the first message/task/thing to do. In mine I'm telling it to call the run method in 5 seconds. Once called the run method will execute every second - symbolised by the 1000 parameter.

The second method is essentially the same as the first except instead of implementing Runnable I create a runnable object in the onCreate() method:

```
Runnable r = new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            counter.setText( " "+i );
            handler.postDelayed( this, 1000 );
            i++;
        }
    };
    handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);
```

I hope this helps.

P.S. Does anyone have any suggestions as to how this can be improved? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a candidate for a [Timer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html) implementation.

Comment: Wouldn't Timer be inappropriate for this? The reason Im saying this is because its Android App and the java.util library shouldn't be used for tasks like this. I read that here - [link](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/timed-ui-updates.html)]

Answer (score 0):

Your thread immediatly exits after `handler2.postDelayed()` call, that's why it doesn't work as a timer. You have to create a loop in the thread.

Comment: What do you suggest then? I want something to continue until told to stop by another button - not fall into an infinite loop. How would you go about it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not against, I could propose my Clock class for it. BTW, beforehand grateful for possible improvements

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.widget.TextView;
/**
 * The class for creating and refreshing many different fields on different layouts,
 * that can hold actual time and/or date in different formats 
 * The formats should be as in http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html. 
 * Only present and visible fields are being actualized, so there is no need to clean the clock list after closing an activity
 * 
 * Examples of use:
 * 
 *      Clock.registerClock((TextView) findViewById(R.id.TimeField), "HH:mm");
 *      Clock.registerClock((TextView) findViewById(R.id.DateField), "d.M.yyyy EEE");
 *      Clock.start(10000L);
 *
 * @author Petr Gangnus
 */
public final class Clock {
    /**
     * the handler that works instead of timer and supports UI
     */
    static private Handler handler = new Handler();
    /**
     * the interval of the time refreshing
     */
    static private long refreshStep;

    /**
     * pairs TextView timer+time/date format
     */
    private TextView clockFace;
    private String format;
    private Clock(TextView clockFace, String format){
        this.clockFace=clockFace;
        this.format=format;
    }
    // here is the list of views containing the visual timers that should be held actual
    static private ArrayList<Clock> clocks=new ArrayList<Clock>();
    /**
     * fills all timer fields by actual time value, according to their formats.
     */
    static private Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {
       public void run() {
           for(Clock clock:clocks){
               showActualTimeDate(clock);
           }
           handler.postDelayed(this,refreshStep);
       }
    };

    //============================================ public members ====================================================================
    /**
     * add a clock to the list of updating clocks
     * @param clockFace - the place where the time or date will be shown 
     * @param format - the format of the time/date 
     * @return
     */
    public static boolean registerClock(TextView clockFace, String format){
        if (clockFace==null) return false;
        if(clocks.contains(clockFace)){
            // old clockFace
            clocks.get(clocks.indexOf(clockFace)).format=format;
        } else {
            // new clockFace
            clocks.add(new Clock(clockFace, format));
        }
        return true;
    }
    /**
     * remove a clock from the updating list
     * @param clockFace
     * @return
     */
    public static boolean unRegisterClock(TextView clockFace){
        if (clockFace==null) return false;
        if(clocks.contains(clockFace)){
            // found clockFace
            clocks.remove(clocks.indexOf(clockFace));
        } else {
            // not found clockFace
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    /**
     * put in the "place" the actual date/time in the appropriate "format"
     * @param place
     * @param format
     */
    public static void showActualTimeDate(Clock clock){
        if (clock.clockFace==null) return;
        if (clock.clockFace.getVisibility()!=TextView.VISIBLE) return;
        Date thisDate=new Date();
        SimpleDateFormat df=new SimpleDateFormat(clock.format);
        clock.clockFace.setText(df.format(thisDate));
    }
    /**
     * start the ticking for all clocks
     * @param step the tick interval
     */
    public static void start(long step) { 
        refreshStep=step;
        handler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
        handler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, 0);
    }
    /**
     * Stopping ticking all clocks (not removing them)
     * the calling could be put somewhere in onStop
     */
    public static void stop() { 
        handler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. create Handler instance and set delayed callback to be called in specified time
   You should try to use postDelayed() from Handler. that points to run() method in Runnable and executes code in it.

   ```
   Handler mHandler = new Handler();
   mHandler.removeCallbacks(mEndPressedState);
   mHandler.postDelayed(mEndPressedState, 400);
   ```
2. Define Runnable that will be triggered after handler timer has passed

   ```
   private final Runnable mEndPressedState = new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
           ((ImageButton)btn).setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_normal));
       }
   };
   ```

In run() then You can also use PostAtTime(). this will cause periodic run() method Calls after some time. Your updateGUI() should be called in run(). Read more here:

[Timer implementation on Android (my blog)](http://looksok.wordpress.com/2012/02/25/timer-implementation-in-android/)